# DELETE rows with prepared query in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is a part of a webservice call to delete a record in MySQL database
But I am getting an error saying "Database Error. Couldn't delete post!"
where is the error in my code.

```
 <?php
        
            //load and connect to MySQL database stuff
            require("config.inc.php");
            
            //initial query
            $query = 'DELETE FROM messages WHERE id =? AND receiver =?';
            $query_params = array($_GET['id'], $_GET['receiver']);
            //execute query
            try {
                $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute(array());

                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Post Successfully DELETED!";
                echo json_encode($response);        
            }
                
            catch (PDOException $ex) {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't delete post!";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }
        ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

`$stmt->execute(array())` should be replaced to `$stmt->execute($query_params)` the params are missing

Comment: Try adding `$ex->getMessage()` to your failure message. That should tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$query_params`

Comment: @MikeW That should read as `$ex->getMessage()` ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- So it should. A pox on these new glasses!

Comment: sorry this is a less concentration tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have prepared the parameters for you statement, but you never actually use them with the statement.

Try changing:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array());
```

to:

```
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
```